# HSQL CSV text table is reading single column over many lines

Tags: csv, hsqldb

I'm experiencing odd behaviour with [HSQL's text tables](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/texttables-chapt.html)

If a quoted column separator is the first column entry then the last column entry of that row will over read onto the next line.

Given a 2 column text table created with:

```
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TEXT TABLE " + archiveName + " ("
            + "message varchar(1000),"
            + "line varchar(1000))");
```

... with a csv file of :

```
",","col 2 line 1"
"col 1 line 2","col 2 line 2"
```

It will read line 1 as :

Col1 : ","

Col2 : "col 2 line 1

"col 1 line 2""

Line 2 will not be read at all. Expected behaviour is:

Line1:

Col1: ","

Col2: "col 2 line 1"

Line2:

Col1: "col 1 line 2"

Col2: "col 2 line 2"

Oddly if you put a space between the quoted separator and closing quote of line1 col1 it will read the file correctly:

```
", ","col 2 line 1"
"col 1 line 2","col 2 line 2"
```

To reproduce create the csv file mentioned and run this :

```
public void schemaCheck() {
final String archiveName = "test";

Connection connection;
try {
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:test", "SA", "");

  try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
    statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + archiveName);
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TEXT TABLE " + archiveName + " ("
            + "message varchar(1000),"
            + "line varchar(1000))");

    statement.executeUpdate("SET TABLE " + archiveName + " SOURCE 'archive/" + archiveName + ".csv;encoding=UTF-8'");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
  }

  try (PreparedStatement statement = connection
          .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + archiveName)) {
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
      System.out.println("Line:");
      System.out.println("First col:");
      System.out.println(result.getString(1));
      System.out.println("Second col:");
      System.out.println(result.getString(2));
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
  }

} catch (SQLException e1) {
  throw new IllegalStateException(e1);
}
}
```

This is using HSQLDB v2.4.0

Things I've tried:

- Ensured the encoding parameter on the table matches the encoding of the csv file
- Set all_quoted=true
- Tested with different line endings CRLF, LF, CR.

These all result in the same outcome: over-reading the last column. The only thing that works other than putting a space in between the quoted field separator and the closing quote is if I ensure that the column in question is not the first column.

Comment: Oddly, it seems that if you put another column before the column with the separator inside it works fine so I've used this as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all_quoted in the text source setting:

```
"SET TABLE " + archiveName + " SOURCE 'archive/" + archiveName + ".csv;encoding=UTF-8;all_quoted=true'"
```

update: This issue was checked and found out to be a bug. It has been fixed for HSQLDB version 2.4.1

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I've tried all the usual stuff like all_quoted, changing file encodings and checking line endings. The issue here isn't that it's treating col 1, line 1 as if it's not got quotes, it's that it's over reading the last column if a field separator is within the first column. I'll edit my question to clarify.